# Launch Facebook messenger Share extension from my iOS app

Tags: iphone, xcode

I'm developing an iPhone app and I want to launch Facebook messenger share extension from when user wants to send a photo to one of his friends.

How can this be done?

I was able to use FBdialog, but this takes the user our of the app and I don't like this option.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want something like sharing a photo from photos app to facebook messenger in native sharing screen?

Answer (score 0):

Your application must have received permissions by the user via the access token (publish_actions). Otherwise, you'll get into the fast-app-switch, which displays a separate page.

Once a user gives your app appropriate permissions, then your FB action can be seamless, without switching across.

In a nutshell, you should implement a "login" method that users "login" to your application using Facebook (more specifically - gives your app permissions to access certain parts of their FB profile), and then you should be able to use native SDK capabilities.

Comment: Thanks. But you are a little confused. The share extension is not a part of the SDK. ?Having the token doesn't help here.

Comment: that sounds bad, why do I need for a user to give permissions, sharing functionality goes outside the app. I am not sharing on users behalf, I am just putting a message together for the user to act and share it. I have exactly the same problem, all other applications work with it so FB Messenger seems to be an exception

Answer (score 0):

If you use **UIActivityViewController** as long as the shared objects (NSString, UIImage, etc) are compatible it should show up automatically on the share list sheet in **iOS 8**.

The user may have to enable it by pressing "More"